# How can I restrict the domain of a sort in Z3 to a single value?

Tags: smt, z3

I'm using the following rule in [my Z3 program](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/wZwF) to make `s` the only possible value of sort `S`.

```
(assert (forall ((t S)) (= t s)))
```

However, the above formula makes [Z3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/) report the following error:

```
Z3: ERROR: WARNING: failed to find a pattern for quantifier (quantifier id: k!8)
```

What is the right way to make sure that the domain of a particular sort has only a single value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message

> Z3: ERROR: WARNING: failed to find a pattern for quantifier (quantifier id: k!8)

is misleading. This is just an warning, the “ERROR” word is there by accident. This was fixed, and will be available in the next release.
The warning just tells the user that the E-matching module will ignore the quantifier.
However, Z3 uses many engines to process quantified formulas. The MBQI module can handle this quantified formula, and build satisfying assignments for problems such as:

> (declare-sort S)
>
> (declare-fun s () S)
>
> (assert (forall ((t S)) (= t s)))
>
> (declare-fun a () S)
>
> (declare-fun b () S)
>
> (assert (= a b))
>
> (check-sat)
>
> (model)

That being said, the quantified formula above is not the best way to specify a sort with a single element.
You can use datatypes to encode enumeration types.
For example, the following command defines a sort S with elements e1 … en.
`(declare-datatypes ((S e1 e2 … en)))`
A sort with only one element can be specified using:
`(declare-datatypes ((S e)))`
The following example is unsatisfiable:

> (declare-datatypes ((S elem)))
>
> (declare-const a S)
>
> (declare-const b S)
>
> (assert (not (= a b)))
>
> (check-sat)

Comment: When I disable the E-matching module, Z3 does no longer report the error (See rise4fun.com/Z3/VPi). Given that our formulas are quantifier free, is disabling the E-matching module a safe workaround?

Comment: Is `declare-datatypes` just a shorthand or it has some other advantage over the expanded version?

Comment: The warning/error is only reported for problems containing quantifiers. So, if you don't use quantifiers, you don't need to disable E-matching. `declare-datatypes` is not a shorthand, it can be used to declare enumeration types, inductive datatypes (such as lists, trees, etc). BTW, we will be releasing Z3 3.0 in the next few days.